# How to install Delphi 4 Python ? ImportError: DLL load failed while importing DelphiVCL: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, delphi, vcl

I tried to follow the steps as per embarcadero tutorial like that:

```
pip install delphivcl
Collecting delphivcl
  Using cached delphivcl-0.1.24-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: delphivcl
Successfully installed delphivcl-0.1.24

Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from delphivcl import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\delphivcl\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    package = new_import()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\delphivcl\__init__.py", line 15, in new_import
    ld = loader.create_module(spec)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing DelphiVCL: The specified module could not be found.
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.11.0 not supported last one supported as of this date is Python 3.10.8